# A specific question about appropriate edits (re questions newly "bumped up to top" by actions of others)

Tags: discussion

When a question is bumped up to the "top of the stack" by a new answer by another user or by edits made to the question or to an existing answer by another user (which might include tag edits), or by "community", is there anything inappropriate about the author of the question (or the author of an answer) taking that opportunity to make additional edits to his or her own work even if they are quite minor? The point being, that the question has already been bumped up the top of the stack. I've taken the viewpoint that this is fine and in some cases have acted accordingly, even noting in the "explain edits" space that the question has recently been bumped up to the top so I took the opportunity to make some minor edits. In some cases I am actually keeping lists of minor typo corrections and other minor changes for some existing questions or answers that I am not planning to actually make until exactly such an opportunity arises. Does the ASE community view this sort of editing unfavorably, or is it fine?

Related (but much broader) ASE meta question-- [What patterns of editing are inappropriate?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4219/34686)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is perfectly fine.

When one of my questions (or questions I have answered) is bumped to the homepage for whatever reason, I usually have a look at it again and sometimes spot something wrong, outdated or missing. This is the perfect time to edit the post, even if it is just a minor typo.

However, I think it is important to do these changes in one edit, rather than splitting them up into many edits over a few hours. This creates unnecessary nuisance ("1 question with new activity" shows up every time). Note that you can see the updated post while typing below (at least in the browser, not sure about the phone). Take that time to read over your post again, before hitting <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>.

Comment: Re "This creates unnecessary nuisance ("1 question with new activity" shows up every time)."  -- thanks for pointing that out, I guess I tend refresh my screen so often I tend not to pay attention to that tag, but I can see your point, thanks.